# Styling list items by using css :nth-child selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have ul list items and i want them to style like following graphic.
Is there way to style it by using css nth-child selector or any other way by using only css.

[image]

```css
ul, ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  background: slategrey;
  border:1px solid white;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  background: lightsteelblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>  
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
    <!--There may be more list items -->
  </ul>
```

Comment: you can do it with class...

Comment: You already managed to format the first list item differently in this example, using :nth-child already - so what question/problem exactly is left now …?

Comment: Can't do it using class, and @CBroe you can understand my question by seeing accepted answer.

Comment: _“you can understand my question by seeing accepted answer”_ - if we need to look at the answer to figure out what the question was, it is a bad question to begin with.

Comment: If you see my graphic you could find a pattern. I could have said data coming from server. My mistake. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `li:nth-child(4n + 1), li:nth-child(4n + 4)`:

```css
ul, ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  background: slategrey;
  border:1px solid white;
}
li:nth-child(4n + 1), li:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  background: lightsteelblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>  
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
    <!--There may be more list items -->
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use selector `li:nth-child(4n), li:nth-child(4n+1)`

```css
ul, ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  background: slategrey;
  border:1px solid white;
}
li:nth-child(4n), li:nth-child(4n+1)  {
  background: lightsteelblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>  
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
    <!--There may be more list items -->
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not categorize them with the class? Even though you can do it with the nth-child but it is hard when you want to change something you will also have to change your formula.

```css
ul, ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  border:1px solid white;
}

li.lightsteelblue {
  background: lightsteelblue;
}

li.slategrey {
  background: slategrey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li class="lightsteelblue">Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li class="slategrey">Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>  
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
    <!--There may be more list items -->
  </ul>
```

Comment: Cant use class. Because this is rendering from api.